# How to Write Data Into Firebase Realtime Database with Cloud Functions when new Data is added to a Specific Child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following realtime database schema:

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqwEJ.png)

I'm working on a social app where a user can like another user. When the user clicks on the like button, a new entry will be added to myLikes->userId list

```
MyLike myLike = new MyLike(userId, System.currentTimeMillis();
         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("myLikes").child(userId).child(System.currentTimeMillis()).setValue(myLike);
```

When the new entry is completed, the cloud function gets triggered to write a new entry in whoLikedMe>userId list for the other User who has been liked.

```
exports.whoLikedMe = functions.database.ref('/myLikes/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // Only edit data when it is first created.
      if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
      }
      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
      }
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const data2 = change.after.val();
      const likedDate = data2.date;
      const myUserId = data2.I_Liked_UserId;
      var likedMe = {
            date: likedDate,
            Who_Liked_Me_UserId: myUserId,
        }

      //get the current date in millis  
      var hrTime = process.hrtime();
      const dateMillis = hrTime[0];
      return admin.database().ref('/WholikedMe/'+myUserId+'/'+hrTime[0]).set(likedMe);
    });
```

The function gets triggered ok but no entries are inserted into the realtime database. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

When I changed:

```
exports.whoLikedMe = functions.database.ref('/myLikes/{userId}')
```

with

```
exports.whoLikedMe = functions.database.ref('/myLikes/{userId}/915170400000')
```

(which adds the hardcoded timestamp to the path) all works fine. The problem is that the timestamp is constantly changing. any idea how to accomplish this with the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wildcard syntax (curly braces) in the following line:

```
return change.after.ref('/WholikedMe/{myUserId}/{hrTime[0]}').set(likeMe)
```

That syntax does not apply to a set statement. You need to use :

```
return change.after.ref('/WholikedMe/' + myUserId + '/' + hrTime[0]).set(likeMe)
```

... I think, doing this on my phone so can't double check. :-)

Comment: you are right. I have edited the code with the syntax correction you suggested but now I have a different error in the logs: Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'WholikedMe.undefined.90.date'. It looks like the properties likedDate  and myUserId are not populated. Also when I put hardcoded values in those properties all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figure d out. In addition to the syntax correction suggested by @GrahamD I had to change

```
exports.whoLikedMe = functions.database.ref('/myLikes/{userId}')
```

with

```
exports.whoLikedMe = functions.database.ref('/myLikes/{userId}/{timestamp')
```

and now all is working fine.

Comment: So please mark my answer as accepted since it resolved the initial problem that the question asked. Thanks.